# Mapping class group of $\Sigma_g \times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

The mapping class group of a topological space $X$ is the group of homeomorphisms $X \to X$ considered up to isotopy.  If $\Sigma_g$ is the closed orientable surface of genus $g$, what is known about the mapping class group of $\Sigma_g \times S^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\Sigma_g \times S^1$ is a surface bundle over the circle it is a Haken 3-manifold. Due to Waldhausen in [On Irreducible 3-manifolds Which are Sufficiently Large](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/haken.pdf) (Haken 3-manifolds) we have the natural homomorphism $\text{Mod}(\Sigma_g \times S^1) \rightarrow \text{Out}(\pi_1(\Sigma_g \times S^1))$ is an isomorphism. Here $\text{Mod}(M) \approx \text{Homeo}(M)/ \text{Homeo}_0(M)$ the mapping class group.

Comment: Can there be interesting outer automorphisms of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g) \times \Bbb Z$ which don't split? In other words whats the difference between $\text{Mod}(\Sigma_g \times S^1)$ and $\text{Mod}(\Sigma_g)$?

Comment: @PVAL-inactive I am not sure about the general case, but when we have $g=0$ then there is the nontrivial map that rotates the 2-sphere by $\theta$ as the $\theta$-coordinate goes around the circle.  So in that case there is a difference.

Comment: @user101010 Unless I am misunderstanding your definition, your map is obviously isotopic to the identity. consider the family maps that rotates the 2-sphere by $(1-t)\theta$. $Out(\Bbb Z)$ is just $\Bbb Z/2$ and certainly in that case every automorphism splits.